# Running a function with args in add_action()

Tags: plugins, actions

I've created a plugin, and it has a function that takes two args, like so:

```
process($tokens, $payloads);
```

... would this work? :

```
add_action ( 'publish_post', process($tokens, $payloads) );
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this cannot work. Haven't you tested your idea?

A simple workaround would be a class:

```
class WPSE_53453_Action_Handler 
{
    public $tokens, $payloads;
    public function process() 
    {
        $tokens   = $this->tokens;
        $payloads = $this->payloads;
        // do something awesome
    }
}

$WPSE_53453           = new WPSE_53453_Action_Handler;
$WPSE_53453->tokens   = array ( 'foo', 'bar' );
$WPSE_53453->payloads = 'hello';

add_action( 'publish_post', array ( $WPSE_53453, 'process' ) );
```

Comment: Doesn't work. This is what I have: http://pastie.org/3979115

Comment: Your code doesn't do anything. What did you expect?

Comment: Ah no, I replaced the actual code with "do something" just to remove the unnecessary parts.